# Extract chisel in alpine docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to install [chisel][1] in my docker under usr/local/bin and try with the following and I got error

```
RUN curl -L https://github.com/jpillora/chisel/releases/download/1.3.1/chisel_linux_amd64.gz | gzip -d - > /usr/local/bin && \
```

the error is :

```
/bin/sh: can't create /usr/local/bin: Is a directory
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16360)
```

but it's dir.... , any idea how to add it to to my image ?

im using docker `alpine:3.10.1`

I've also tried this

```
RUN curl -sSL https://github.com/jpillora/chisel/releases/download/1.3.1/chisel_linux_amd64.gz | gzip -d - > /usr/local/bin/chisel && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chisel
```

and got error:

````
/bin/sh: can't create /usr/local/bin/chisel: Permission denied
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16360)

```


https://github.com/jpillora/chisel


  [1]: https://github.com/jpillora/chisel
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this:

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache wget
RUN cd  /usr/local/bin && wget  https://github.com/jpillora/chisel/releases/download/1.3.1/chisel_linux_amd64.gz && gzip -d chisel_linux_amd64.gz
RUN mv /usr/local/bin/chisel_linux_amd64 /usr/local/bin/chisel && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chisel
RUN chisel -v
```

result:

```
ls /usr/local/bin/
chisel
```

Comment: thanks! I try it but when at the end im adding `RUN chisel -v` I got permission denied error, any idea?

Comment: btw when I run the command `chisel -v ` I got return 1 but it prints the version, any idea how we can omit it ? I mean print the version but without returning error...

Comment: chisel -v || exit 0

Answer (score 1):

You can use below using curl

```
FROM alpine:3.10.1
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache curl
RUN curl -sSL https://github.com/jpillora/chisel/releases/download/1.3.1/chisel_linux_amd64.gz | gzip -d - > /usr/local/bin/chisel && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chisel
```

Container Output:

[image: ls -l /usr/local/bin]